# TikZ Externalize & Linegoal conflict?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-external

I'm new to stackexchange, and did not find any information about this issue. I encounter an error whenever I try to use the TikZ's externalize along with (unrelated to TikZ pictures-) `\linegoal`. My engine is MikTeX on Win7 with TeXstudio. As soon as the `linegoal` package is used along with `externalize`, `linegoal` throws an error:

```
! Package linegoal Error: \linegoal does not work if output file are disabled 
(linegoal) please check the value of \if@filesw!.
```

A MWE is:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{linegoal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) -- (1,1);
  \end{tikzpicture}

  \parbox[t]{\linegoal}{test}
\end{document}
```

Does anyone have an idea on how to solve that?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `external` library explicitly suppresses the generation of auxiliary LaTeX files (because their generation is not thread-safe).

It uses `\nofiles` to disable the handling of `.aux` files while it generates external graphics. It will use custom functionality to allow auxiliary data like `\label` and `\ref`.

Thus, the short answer is: sorry, these two packages are incompatible.

---

That said, there may be more-or-less reliable work-arounds. It is like opening a warranty seal...

What you can try is to temporarily hack `\nofiles` such that `tikz` believes that it disabled them although it did not:

```
\let\oldnofiles=\nofiles
\let\nofiles=\relax
\tikzexternalize
\let\nofiles=\oldnofiles
```

with this hack, your minimal example compiles. However, it may fail utterly. Perhaps you should use `\tikzexternalize[mode=list and make]` or something like that - the default `mode=convert with system call` is doomed to fail eventually due to unavoidable race conditions around these aux files.

Comment: The workaround works perfectly for my document! Thanks very much for the answer.