# Are tikzmark and tikzexternalize incompatible? [targeting sub-nodes]

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-external, tikzmark

Here's a MWE using tikzmark to draw an arrow connecting two sub-nodes in a tree:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
%\tikzexternalize
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} 
  \node {A} 
    child {node {\subnode{end}{B}}}
    child {node {C \subnode{start}{B} E}}; 
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  remember picture,
  overlay]
  \draw[->] (start.south) to [out=south west,in=south east] (end.south);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

As expected, this yields the following output (calling `pdflatex` with `-shell-escape`):

[image: tikzmark works]

However, if `%\tikzexternalize` is un-commented, compilation fails, with the following error:

```
! Package pgf Error: No shape named start is known.
```

Are tikzmark and tikz externalize incompatible? If so, are they *fundamentally* incompatible?

**Edited to add:** if fundamentally incompatible, is there any alternative way to execute something like the image in this post -- that is, to target a sub-node with (e.g.) an arrow?

Comment: Almost certainly!  Do you need the `\draw` command to be part of a different `tikzpicture`?  It ought to work if you put it as part of the original one.

Comment: No dice. No compilation errors, but the arrow is not drawn correctly. See [here](http://imgur.com/ora4A5K) for what results (the "arrow" is at the bottom-right end of the `A`).

Comment: As far as I can tell, yes, they are incompatible. When you externalise, the picture is typeset once. After that, unless the code changes, the previously typeset version is used. At least, this is the typical usage (you can change it). But `tikzmark` relies on multiple compilations. Maybe there is a way around it, but I now always disable externalisation for pictures which use `tikzmark`.

Comment: This is roughly what I figured, though I am still sad to hear it.

Comment: You need to force it to compile twice which externalize won't naturally do.  Use the force remake key.

Comment: Yes, I realize that. Doing so doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: @LoopSpace I haven't looked into it, but that isn't enough I don't think. Having said that, I've not tried it with `\subnode` and if it were going to work at all, it would presumably be in that case. (Because the later commands are part of the same picture.)

Comment: Can you not just not externalise pictures where you use `\subnode`?

Comment: @cfr That is an option. But in my case, not a good one, since my trees frequently require arrows targeting sub-nodes.

Comment: Okay, the basic problem is that the externalisation library disables writing the aux files for the pictures and tikzmark relies on saving information in the auxfile.  So you need to re-enable the auxfile, but even doing that then it doesn't work properly (I get that the arrow is the right size but displaced) probably due to the page cropping.

Comment: Your nodes with subnodes, are they all single line text?  (ie no line breaks)

Comment: @LoopSpace not sure exactly what you mean: are they all single-line text in the source code, or in the output? Assuming the latter, the answer is negative; some of my figures look [like so](http://imgur.com/8W8GNF2).

Comment: I meant in the output.  I was thinking of building up the text as a series of actual nodes (or rather as a multipart node) but I don't think that would be easy with multi-lines.  How about putting the pictures in individual files, compiling them separately, and `\includegraphics`ing them into the master document?

Comment: @SimonC as you predicted, a little esoteric indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Submitted for your consideration. Here is a MWE that gets pretty close by using `standalone` in lieu of `external`. The main file (`test.tex`) looks like so:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[mode=buildnew]{standalone}
\begin{document} 
\includestandalone{tree}
\end{document}
```

And `tree.tex` looks like so (essentially pasting the answer given by Gonzalo Medina [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255472/targeting-proper-parts-of-nodes-in-forest)):

```
\documentclass[border=20pt]{standalone}

%necessary for tikzmark and xetex to play nicely
\newcount\pdftexversion
\pdftexversion140 \def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-dvipdfm.def}

\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
for tree={s sep=20pt}
[A t\subnode{endc}{e}st text
  [B
    [\subnode{enda}{C},
    ] 
  ]
  [D
    [\subnode{endb}{E}
    ]
    [\subnode{startc}{F}
      [G
      ]
      [H
        [\subnode{startb}{John} see \subnode{starta}{x}
        ]
      ] 
    ]
  ] 
]
\end{forest}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  remember picture,
  overlay,
  >=latex
]
\draw[cyan,thick,->]
  (starta.south) --
  ++(0pt,-10pt) -| 
  (enda.south);
\draw[red!80!black,thick,->]
  (startb.south) --
  ++(0pt,-5pt) -| 
  (endb.south);
\draw[green!80!black,thick,->]
  (startc) to[out=60,in=90,looseness=1.4]
  (endc.north);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

(The `border=20pt` is necessary because `standalone` does not take the movement arrows into account.)

Compiling the main file with `latexmk -pvc -xelatex test.tex --shell-escape` gives something that looks correct. Progress! However, `latexmk` then enters an endless loop. Why is not exactly clear. Modifying `.latexmkrc` as detailed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/63320/77582) does not seem to help, nor does calling `latexmk` with the `-recorder-` flag.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a somewhat hackish way that works with your given example.  Try it on some more complicated ones to see how robust it is.

The first issue is that when externalising, TikZ invokes `\nofiles` and so nothing gets written to the aux file.  Since `tikzmark` relies on stuff written to the aux file, that's a fairly major obstacle to getting it to work with externalisation.  To enable that, we steal the idea from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/75030/86, which also means that we have to use `list and make` rather than `system call` when externalising.

That doesn't solve everything, though, because even when stuff is written to the aux file then it isn't written right.  There's an offset which might be due to page cropping, but might be due to something else entirely.  Fortunately, it is consistent.  So what we need to do is put a subnode somewhere known (for example, at the origin) and then use that to compute the offset.  Then we can adjust all other subnodes by this offset.

To avoid conflict, I've defined a new subnode command `\extsubnode` which does this adjustment.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/255543/86}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\let\oldnofiles=\nofiles
\let\nofiles=\relax
\tikzexternalize[mode=list and make]
\let\nofiles=\oldnofiles

\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\makeatletter

\tikzset{
  every picture/.style={
    execute at begin picture={%
      \edef\outermostid{\pgfpictureid}%
      \node {\subnode{origin\outermostid}{}};
    }
  }
}

\newcommand\extsubnode[3][]{%
  \begingroup
  \pgfmark{#2}%
  \setbox\pgfnodeparttextbox=\hbox\bgroup #3\egroup
  \def\tikz@shape{rectangle}%
  \def\tikz@anchor{center}%
  \def\tikz@fig@name{#2}%
  \tikzset{every subnode/.try,#1}%
  \pgfpointorigin
  % there is a spurious space inserted by the next point scan so we
  % box it to ignore it
  \setbox\tikz@tempbox=\hbox\bgroup
  \tikz@scan@one@point\pgfutil@firstofone(origin\outermostid)\relax
  \global\pgf@xa=\pgf@x
  \global\pgf@ya=\pgf@y
  \egroup
  \tikz@scan@one@point\pgfutil@firstofone(pic cs:#2)\relax
  \advance\pgf@x by -\pgf@xa
  \advance\pgf@y by -\pgf@ya
  \advance\pgf@x by .5\wd\pgfnodeparttextbox
  \advance\pgf@y by .5\ht\pgfnodeparttextbox
  \advance\pgf@y by -.5\dp\pgfnodeparttextbox
  \pgftransformshift{}%
  \setbox\@tempboxa=\hbox\bgroup
  \pgfutil@ifundefined{pgf@sh@s@\tikz@shape}%
  {\PackageError{pgf}{Unknown shape ``\tikz@shape''}{}}%
  {%
    {%
      \let\pgf@sh@savedmacros=\pgfutil@empty% MW
      \let\pgf@sh@savedpoints=\pgfutil@empty%
      \def\pgf@sm@shape@name{\tikz@shape}% CJ % TT added prefix!
      \csname pgf@sh@s@\tikz@shape\endcsname%
      \pgf@sh@savedpoints%
      \pgf@sh@savedmacros% MW
      \pgftransformshift{%
        \pgf@sh@reanchor{\tikz@shape}{\tikz@anchor}%
        \pgf@x=-\pgf@x%
        \pgf@y=-\pgf@y%
      }%
      \expandafter\pgfsavepgf@process\csname pgf@sh@sa@\tikz@fig@name\endcsname{%
       \pgf@sh@reanchor{\tikz@shape}{\tikz@anchor}% FIXME : this is double work!
      }%
      % Save the saved points and the transformation matrix
      \edef\pgf@node@name{\tikz@fig@name}%
      \ifx\pgf@node@name\pgfutil@empty%
      \else%
        \expandafter\xdef\csname pgf@sh@ns@\pgf@node@name\endcsname{\tikz@shape}%
        \edef\pgf@sh@@temp{\noexpand\gdef\expandafter\noexpand\csname pgf@sh@np@\pgf@node@name\endcsname}%
        \expandafter\pgf@sh@@temp\expandafter{\pgf@sh@savedpoints}%
        \edef\pgf@sh@@temp{\noexpand\gdef\expandafter\noexpand\csname pgf@sh@ma@\pgf@node@name\endcsname}% MW
        \expandafter\pgf@sh@@temp\expandafter{\pgf@sh@savedmacros}% MW
        \pgfgettransform\pgf@temp
        \expandafter\xdef\csname pgf@sh@nt@\pgf@node@name\endcsname{\pgf@temp}%
        \expandafter\xdef\csname pgf@sh@pi@\pgf@node@name\endcsname{\pgfpictureid}%
      \fi%
    }%
  }%
  \egroup
  \box\pgfnodeparttextbox
  \endgroup
}


\makeatother



\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node {A} 
    child {node[draw] {\extsubnode{end}{B}}}
    child {node {C\extsubnode{start}{B}E}}; 
  \draw[->] (start.south) to [out=south
      west,in=south east] (end.south);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! Afraid it's not working for me: fails with `xelatex`, and even with `pdflatex`, [the output](http://imgur.com/j0ki0mI) is incorrect.

Comment: xelatex has other issues.  With pdflatex, did you run the make command twice?

Comment: Afraid so. If I call `make -f`, it tells me `All images exist now. Use make -B to re-generate them.` If I call `make -B`, it tells me `make: Nothing to be done for test.makefile`.

Comment: You need to do `make -B -f filename`.  Though thinking about it, it might be best to modify the makefile to do two runs on each figure.